# Does joins in Tableau effect performance?

Tags: mysql, join, tableau-api

I have a Mysql database with tables A, B, C and D. A has a relationship between B, C and D, but B, C and D does not have relationship among them. As to generate graphs in Tableau, data should exist like a table, so I created a joined relationship among them in following way: A-(right join B), A-(right join C), A-(right join D) so that all rows in B, C and D will be present. I would like to know if this kind of join effects data base performance as a single table is being created in Tableau with all the fields in A, B, C and D? Also, am I following the right method?

Comment: You should probably create a view in MySQL with the information you want and use the view to load the data into Tableau.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I'm new to tableau. So,please take this question. I'm thinking of setting up a live connection. Live connection means data will not be loaded into tableau right. It's just that Tableau queries and fetches the results right?

Comment: . . I'm only tangentially familiar with Tableau.  But with any application of that type, it is usually better to do the joins in the database.  A simple interface is to use a view defined in the database.

Comment: Tableau's data processing engine looks at several factors when deciding how to process the query. Sometimes it's a straight query to the db, sometimes it's done in memory. You also have the option of using the Custom SQL option in the data source and Tableau passes that sql straight to the db. There are some performance monitoring tools available for you to try different methods and watch where bottlenecks might be. If you don't need up-to-the-minute live data, I would strongly suggest using data extracts. They give huge performance gains.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have a doubt here- If I extract data, does that mean Tableau stores data in its own memory? If that's the case, it is not ideal for large data bases right?

Comment: If it is a join and a live connection the only thing that matters is how well your DB server processes the join. Only the *results* of queries to the joined tables will need to be passed to Tableau. If the DB handles these well Tableau performance won't be affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a Tableau data extract, the performance of your query will not be a factor once you are in the Desktop environment. From my experience "Large database" is pretty subjective. I have read comments from those using extracts of tens of millions of records with great success though. If your set is larger, I would still suggest trying the extract as a test because the performance of your query wont matter as much. Tableau will store data in memory but because of the tde setup, you can have more data than memory when necessary. If you want to read more on how extracts work and improve performance then check out this link from Tableau's blog.  A TDE will also perform better if hosted on server.

[Understanding TDEs](http://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2014/7/understanding-tableau-data-extracts-part1)